# Google Map not accessible in IE/Safari

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to integrate google map in my project.. On Firefox, map works fine. but in IE and Safari it throws an error saying

> In IE it says GEO location is not available and throwing error message.
>
> In Safari getting popup says simply ERROR(2) and throwing same error message.

what can i do for ot..

Also, i have created a menu for my project, the menu bar is fine in firefox but it is not showing on Google Chrome and Opera.
Please give me suggestions and respective code for this.

Comment: Please only ask one question at once. And there is nowhere near enough information to help here, although I guess that the code is attempting to use HTML5 geolocation and some browsers can't handle it (or have it disabled). What debugging have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Hi to solve your problem, try to read this [documentation](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=21849)

Enjoy